# Spring AOP execution with method name doesn't match

Tags: spring, spring-aop

I just tried an `@Around` for a method defined with my repository interface.

```java
@Repository
public interface MyRepository {

    Page<Some> getAllSome();
}
```

With my Aspect I can't specify the `getAllSome` method.

```java
@Aspect
@Component
public class MyRepositoryAspect {

    @Around("execution(* my.package.MyRepository.*(..))") // works
    //@Around("execution(* my.package.MyRepository.getAllSome(..))") // does't work
    public Object aroundGetAllSome(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
    }
}
```

Why the version with `.getAllSome(..)` doesn't work? How can I match a specific method?

Comment: Could you please share an MCVE ? The expression should work. By any chance an internal method call that prevents the advise ?

Comment: I agree with R.G and even quickly tried in my playground project. It does work. So if it does not for you, your real situation is different from the (pseudo) code you posted here. Hence, the [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is the best way for you to show real code and get a real answer.